# circular animation using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create an animation for a three-letter word. For now, take the word XYZ. The idea is that each letter of XYZ will move in a circular path of different radii and directions (Like one letter moving right, another left, and bottom) before coming back to the original position. I have tried using different forms of code for this but am failing because I don't clearly understand how to animate circular motion with a fixed origin. Will be helpful if anyone could share how to do this.  I am also attaching part of my code

```css
.animation-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 10rem;
  left: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.letter {
  animation: move-letter 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes move-letter {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-container">
  <div class="letter X">X</div>
  <div class="letter Y">Y</div>
  <div class="letter Z">Z</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Thor, I slowed down the animation and made it infinite to better see what's going on...

Comment: It seems you need three animations with the same timing, one for each letter. Search online for *css animate text along path* and find a few insightful examples.

Comment: Reminds me, I created this ages ago [Text on a 3D circular path V2, with range sliders](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/bGrvKoV), but it may be a bit too much to swallow, be warned.  Read the warning in the demo, it has a 2D/3D display bug I still haven't resolved. (...duh, I sometimes toy with it, just to clear my head...)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you actually want, but you definitely need three different animations (i.e. with different settings), and 3 or more stages per animation, returning to the first position in each case:

```css
.animation-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 10rem;
  left: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.letter.X {
  animation: move-letter_x 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.letter.Y {
  animation: move-letter_y 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.letter.Z {
  animation: move-letter_z 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@keyframes move-letter_x {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(20px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes move-letter_y {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(80px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes move-letter_z {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(140px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-container">
  <div class="letter X">X</div>
  <div class="letter Y">Y</div>
  <div class="letter Z">Z</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just too slow of a thinker to come up with stuff like this within a reasonable time. Got my vote instead...

Comment: hey @johannes, thanks for the suggestion. Yes, as you said, we need three keyframes to animate each letter. I tried it before, but the problem I was facing was that you needed to translate the letter to the circumference of the circle. This will make the letter start at a different point and end at a different point than where it was originally. Is it possible to make the letter move from the place they are already at, "top:10rem; left:50%;" in this case